# Mac OS and Node.js sudo cp -R - Operation not permitted, but in native terminal it gives no error

Tags: node.js, macos, macos-catalina

I am trying to execute command `cp -R` using npm package "sudo-prompt". It gives an error:
`Operation not permitted`

I suppose that's a problem with the new Mac OS feature "System Integrity Protection" because when I use the native system terminal and input this command it does not throw any errors `sudo cp -R`. What can I do to avoid this problem?

I need to run the `cp -R` command without incursion into client's system settings, unless it is possible with the sudo prompt.